# Python -V not working or returning any error on Windows 10

Tags: python

I tried to upgrade python version. It didn't work so I uninstalled python from my system. Deleted from Path and re-installed it. Ever since the reinstall

```
python -V
```

doesn't work. I have set the path manually and didn't work. Uninstalled and tried again, this time checked the tick-box that says add python to path.
No matter what I do can't seem to get the commands working.[image]

As like the picture I get nothing. The version or anything else.
How am I to fix this problem?

Comment: Try `py` instead of `python`. Or `python3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Reason for the behaviour

Your system is using wrong `python.exe`. (not the one you installed, but one coming with Windows)

#### How to fix this?

It's completely ok to keep the `C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps` on you PATH, but make sure that your python installation folder (folder with `python.exe`)  is in your PATH *above* the `C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps`, because the PATH is checked *in order* from top to bottom (or left to right).

[image]

To edit the environment variables, use Win -> type "envir" to the search -> Edit environment variables for your account -> Environment Variables... -> Select from the top list (user list) the "Path" and press "Edit...".

#### Notes

- You can check what `python.exe` your command is using in Powershell with `Get-Command python`.
- You probably want to also include the `/Scripts` folder of your python installation to the PATH. (there are common tools like `pip.exe`, and any `.exe` coming from a package, such as `ipython.exe`)
- This problem happens because there is a default `python.exe`in newer Windows 10 versions. See: [Who put Python in the Windows 10 May 2019 Update?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-the-windows-10-may-2019-update/)
- The *Process* PATH is not updated if you edit the User or System PATH; you need to restart the Powershell to make the changes visible. If you use terminal of an IDE, you need to close all windows for the process once.

Comment: It is OK to keep the file. but why do we need it :-)

Comment: I don't personally know who would need it. Perhaps MS thought it would be helpful command for someone. Removing the WindowsApps `python.exe` *might* have some undesired side effects since it comes with the system. Also it might come back with some Windows update :) See [Typing “python” on Windows 10 (version 1903) command prompt opens Microsoft store](https://superuser.com/questions/1437590/typing-python-on-windows-10-version-1903-command-prompt-opens-microsoft-stor) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I had to move the path variable up and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the file `c:/Users/<user>/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe`